# Is 'params'ing a string good enough to prevent occasional reader to read it?

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I need some light form of obfuscation, most methods of "obfuscating" strings in C# are cumbersome to use, the simplest thing I can think of is doing the following:

```
public string GetString( params char[] chars)
{
    return new string(chars);
}
```

however my fear is that the compiled code after optimization will result in something that is easy to read anyway.

Example usage:

```
GetString('t','r','i','a','l','','v','e','r','s','i','o','n');
```

Isn't there any option to obufscate constant strings in Visual Studio?

I just need to **avoid someone with a text editor can use "find and replace"** to remove the string from executable. I need no more protection (just stop occasional user). Of course most obfusctaion methods are so hard to use that they introduce to much effort for so little gain that I wanted just to know if using `params char[]` is enough protection or under certain conditions the compiler is likely to optimize the binary to the same of

```
new string("trial version");
```

Comment: How about encoding it as Base64?

Comment: I think the input string will be still visible in executable right? I just want to avoid users find the "Trial version" string and replace characters with something else. (which I can do myself with notepad++ in 2 seconds)

Comment: I was thinking about something like that: return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String("VHJpYWwgdmVyc2lvbg=="));

Comment: Anything you do is probably going to be easily circumvented using something like Telerik JustDecompile. If you encrypt all your sensitive strings, the decompiler will show the code that you use to decrypt it - unless you did something like decrypt it using an unmanaged DLL. That's a possibility but now it's starting to get more fiddly.

Comment: yes, I just want to avoid someone with a text editor can find and replace the string, nothing more

Comment: If you want to prevent people from changing your binaries, [sign them with a Strong Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Comment: They could unsign, of course the signature will be no longer valid ^^ but they would remove such text string anyway

Comment: Encode or encrypt it, or use a professional obfuscator. This attempt would only make it hard for you to develop.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, as you pointed "just stop occasional user" is to use Base64 encoding. In your code you would have:

```
public string GetProgramLicenseName()
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
        System.Convert.FromBase6‌4String("VHJpYWwgdmV‌​yc2lvbg=="));
}
```

Which won't be simplified by compiler. The decoding will be done at runtime.

Note however, it is a very weak way of obfuscating. You could try something more sophisticated:

- encryption/decryption
- use professional obfuscator
- sign the assembly with strong name to avoid change in it
- call external server to check the license/download crucial part of program

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to check. I compiled the following code and checked the resulting binary:

```
private static string regularString = "Test";
private static string ickyString = "T" + "r" + "i" + "a" + "l";
private static string ickyString2 = new string(new [] {'V', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n'});
```

In all cases (the normal string, string concatenation and the char-array), the characters could be found in the executable, separated by `null`s. No difference between the three representations.

As the comments and other answers state, the simplest way to defeat a casual find/replace hacker is to use a simple ROT-13 or Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the string in binary:

```
public string GetString( Byte[] myString)
{
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myString);
}

GetString(new byte[] { 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x73, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e });
```